# Why is $y=h(x)$ deemed as a solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can some one explain why does $y=h(x)$ deemed as a solution to a given ODE concept?

it seems like an important concept, and simple too. But I must be missing some peace in this logic. Can some one explain this is please?

Update:
I went back to the text and found the source of my confusion. I mistook "if" for symbol meaning function. Now the following phrase means a lot:

> "y=h(x) is a solution to ODE on interval I, IF h(x) is defined and differentiable throughout the interval, and as such that eq. becomes an identity if y and y' are replaced with h and h' respectively."

Comment: Edits and improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important to understand what an *equation* is in the first place.  Heuristically, it's a statement about an unknown quantity that is true or false for various values of the quantity [yes, this is also true for inequalities and other relations, but bear with me.]

For instance, $x^2 - 4x + 3 = 0$ is an *algebraic* equation.  The unknown is a number $x$, and the statement is that "(the number) squared minus four times (the number) plus three is zero".  A thousand years ago, before algebraic notation was invented, they were actually written out that way!

This equation can be checked for various values of $x$.  If substituting a certain value for $x$ results in a true statement, we say the equation is *satisfied* by that value.  For instance, does $x=0$ satisfy $x^2-4x+3 = 0$?  No, because the left-hand side evaluates to $3$ while the right-hand side is $0$.  Does $x=1$ satisfy the equation?  Yes, because $1^2-4+3 = 0$.

You probably know of techniques for algorithmically solving algebraic equations.  But factoring or the quadratic formula are more complex than just checking solutions.

A *differential equation* is a statement about an unknown *function* $y(x)$ that involves derivatives of the function.  For example, $y' = 2y$ is a very succinct way to express the relation that the derivative of $y$ is a multiple (in this case, $2$) of $y$.  When Newton wrote *Principia*, his [second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_2nd_Law) was written not as $F = ma$, but *the change in momentum is proportional to the force applied*.

Just like with algebraic equations, the statement that a function is a solution to a differential equation is a matter of checking if substituting that function into the equation results in a true statement.  For instance, with $y'=2y$, you might guess that $y=x^2$ is a solution.  But substituting $y=x^2$ into $y'=2y$ gives $2x = 2(x^2) = 2x^2$.  This equation of functions is not true for all $x$.  However, if you try $y=e^{2x}$, then substituting, we have $y'=2e^{2x}$ and $2y=2e^{2x}$.  Since these are identical, the function satisfies the equation.

Again, as with algebraic equations, differential equations are tougher to *solve* than to simply check solutions.  But the idea that a function is a solution is just a matter of substitution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Though you lost me on Newton's "Princicia". So does it all mean that a solution to any given ODE is some function of X?

Comment: What confuses me, is when in the book, when they explain ODE concept, it states "we know that the solution of ODE is $y=h(x)$...". But how do we know that? Where is this coming from. Is this just a condition of any and all ODE? and if not, then it's just not ODE in the first place?

Comment: @JekDenys: That quote would need more context to explain better.  But it could just mean that "We know the solution of an ODE is a function.  Let's call that function $h(x)$."

Comment: Thanks for your help and for such a detailed reply. I went back to the text and found the source of my confusion. I mistook "if" for symbol meaning function. Now the following phrase means a lot: "y=h(x) is a solution to ODE on interval I, IF h(x) is defined and differentiable throughout the interval, and as such that eq. becomes an identity if y and y' are replaced with h and h' respectively."